# Is SDL_FreeSurface() equivalent to free() in terms of functionality?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-1.2

I'm trying to free a bunch of things with different types, and so I think I might be able to free all of
them using one function by adding them to a pile of `void *` cells.

My question is: is it safe to save an `SDL_Surface*` as `void *` and use the `free()` function without the need of `SDL_FreeSurface()`?

Comment: I am not familiar with `SDL_FreeSurface` specifically. But usually when libraries provide functions for creating/destroying objects, they are not equivalent to malloc/free and handle some stuff specific to the library.

Comment: Is a surface a simple type with no suballocations? No? Then why would you think this is safe?

Comment: I thought I could free all of the pointers at once. So now come to think of it, it is a no because `SDL_Surface` structure already has pointers underneath. Thanks for pointing the suballocations term out.

Comment: There are two aspects to the question: (Q1) Can an `SDL_Surface*` be converted to `void*`? (A1) Yes, and back again. (Q2) Can `free()` be used to free an `SDL_Surface` allocated by the SDL library? (A2) No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have to use `SDL_FreeSurface`. (Evidence: [what it does](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/cae6b4489d0828bd70ae4ec559bec132d5f93ca6/src/video/SDL_surface.c#L1538))

Except in specific cases, it's never safe to just use one free function instead of another. You `free` things you allocate with `malloc`. You `CloseHandle` things opened with `CreateFile` (on Windows). You `fclose` files you opened with `fopen`. And so on.